# Upright (rather than italic) 'd' using Diffcoef

Tags: diffcoeff

My understanding of the documentation of package `Diffcoeff` is that it uses upright 'd's as default. e.g. at the top of page 10 you are referred to section 3.4 to *change* the default to math-italic. However, I get math-italic as default even in this very simple MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}

\begin{document}
\[
   \diff xy=3
\]
\end{document}
```

that results in

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, with v5 (released 2 days ago) it will be the default behaviour (upright d). So you can simply upgrade it. // You can use `texdoc diffcoeff` to view the doc of your installation.